# passing a functor to a constructor in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, functor

Would that be possible to help me to pass a functor, such as :

```
struct BFunc
{
    double operator()(const double x, const double y, const double z){
        return 0.1;
        }
};
```

to a the constructor of a class:

```
class foo
{
    int n;
public:
foo();
foo(int nn, &bfunc):n(nn),f(func()){        
    } 
double getResult(double x){
        return f(x);
    }   
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: What is `f` in the constructor and `getResult` functions? You don't have any such data member declared.

Comment: What exactly do you want to pass? A function with a specific signature? Any object which overloads `operator()`? Or an instance of `BFunc`? I assume you want to store it in some member called f, but at the moment you ary trying to call this f with one parameter while your `BFunc::operator()` takes 3 arguments.

Comment: There's nothing all that special about a functor. Its simply an object that's overloaded the `operator()` so you can pass it like you would any object. This might get you on the right path http://rextester.com/WQVBI94166

Comment: Please clean up the code. If nothing else, please fix the formatting at least.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your quick response. I solved it, by declaring a variable of type functor as bellow. But I was wondering if it is possible to do it without that. The point is I wanted to create a class, which I pass a function as boundary condition and a range to it, so it creates a 2D or 3D matrix of coordinates which gives zero to all points inside and zero to all points outside. I wanted to make it as general as possible. Eventually I ended up to follow following method.

```
using namespace std;

struct functor {
    int a=11;
    int operator () (int x) const {
    cout << a << endl;
    return 2*x;
    }
};

class myclass {
    int y=0;
    functor af;// ** I did not wanted to have this line and make it generic  **  //
public:
    template <typename F> myclass(const F & f):af(f){
        //af=f;//auto af(f);
        y=f(5);
        cout<<"y is"<<y<<endl;
        int z=af(5);
        cout<<"z is"<<z<<endl;
        cout<<"    why   "<<typeid(af).name()<<endl;
    }
    int getFuncX(int x){
        int y=af(x);
        return y;
    }


};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    functor f = {5};
    myclass c(f);
    cout<<" See What happens:  "<<c.getFuncX(71)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Sorry if it is messy! As you guessed I am a beginner.
Thanks